# How to avoid logging an error when aborting a pipeline

Tags: sitecore-commerce, pipelines

By default an error is logged when I abort a pipeline in Sitecore XC9.

For example;

```
context.Abort("Abort pipeline", context);
```

Sometimes I want to abort a pipeline without logging an error, i.e. when it's valid to preempt the execution of the pipeline.

How to do this?

Comment: @Dan Sinclair why did you remove the sitecore-commerce tag?

Comment: Because this is not a commerce-specific question/solution. This appears to apply to any pipeline abort command; is that right?

Comment: No this is for XC only

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add a magic `"Ok|"` string to the abort message, e.g:

```
context.Abort("Ok|Abort pipeline", context);
```

It turns out that the implementation of `Abort` checks for the magic `"Ok|"` string:

```
public override void Abort(string message, object context)
{
   base.Abort(message, context);
   if (message.Contains("Ok|"))
      return;
   this.Logger.LogError(string.Format("PipelineAbort:{0}", (object) message), Array.Empty());
}
```

Comment: wow, nice catch